# How to imitate list() with own function / method in PHP?

Tags: php, list

We all know calls like this:

```
list($a, $b) = explode(':', 'A:B');
```

But how to make a custom function that can be use the same way?

```
$obj->mylist($a, $b) = explode(':', 'A:B');
mylist($a, $b) = explode(':', 'A:B');
```

If i use the above lines of code i always get: **"Can't use method return value in write context in [...]"**
How to define the function / class method to accept that type of assignment? How to the the array returned by explode()? Via func_get_args()?

Sure, there are other ways to assign the result of explode(), but that is not the subject of this question. E.g.

```
$obj->mylist($a, $b, explode(':', 'A:B'));
mylist($a, $b, explode(':', 'A:B'));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is impossible as you cannot write a method that can be used as an lvalue.

`list()` is not a function but a language construct, that's why it can be used in the way it's used.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. [`list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) is a language construct, not a function, and there is no way in PHP to make a function behave like that. It will cause a syntax error.

What meaning would you want from `mylist($a, $b) = explode(':', 'A:B');` anyways? If it were list instead of mylist it would just be equivalent to:

```
$arr = explode(':', 'A:B');
$a = $arr[0];
$b = $arr[1];
unset($arr);
```

How could you redefine the meaning of that for a function on the left? With your object example you can do something like:

```
list($obj->a, $obj->b) = explode(':', 'A:B');
```

What behaviour exactly are you trying to get? Perhaps there is another way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PHP allows array-type data to be "spread" into individual method parameters via the spread operator.

Code: [(Demo)](https://3v4l.org/jYLdA)

```
class Test
{
    public function mylist(string $a, string $b): void
    {
        var_dump($a, $b);
    }
}

$obj = new Test();
$obj->mylist(...explode(':', 'A:B'));
```

Output:

```
string(1) "A"
string(1) "B"
```

---

If your goal is not to directly pass the values into a method as parameters, then perhaps your requirements aren't very clear and we should be told what `mylist()` does.